# VB.net Main method not executing

Tags: vb.net, program-entry-point, c#-to-vb.net

I've taken up learning vb.net having come from a C# background.

I was trying to reprogram a simple C# winforms program I had, which took command line parameters to determine what it did. In C#, there is always a main method to accept these arguments.

From what I've read, vb.net implements a main method for you once you specify the starting form, unless you make one yourself. Which is fine, but the one I've implemented seems to get ignored, I've put break points in to see if the code even get looked at, but nothing. The main sub is in the class declaration of the startup form like so:

```
Public Class FrontScreen
    <STAThread()> _
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim mainWindow As FrontScreen = New FrontScreen()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello! I'm exectuing!")
        Application.Run(mainWindow)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Obviously I'm going to put more code in the main method later, but right now I'd just like to get the message box to come up to show that my main sub is actually being executed. I'm probably doing something really obvious wrong, but from the examples I've seen I can't tell what. Any ideas?

Thanks, Andy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into your project properties:

1. Remove the checkbox from "Enable application framework".
2. In the "Startup object" dropdown box, select the entry "Sub Main".

[image: Sub Main properties]

Comment: Yes, that worked! I now have a message box, knew it was something simple. I'm at the stage learning a new language where _everything_ confuses me, but its getting better. I'll have to have a read up about the application framework I think. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew: Here's a nice article about that, if you want to know what the Application Framework actually does: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx. If you want to keep your application close to the C# version, you probably don't want to use it. For a pure VB application, it has a few nice features.

Comment: I find it crazy that today there's not even a "startup object". Now  it's just startup FORM.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the command line arguments then another option besides intercepting the `Main` method is to use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but I need them at the program start up. And as I'm copying a C# program, I want to keep it as similar as possible and use the 'Main'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not that the program does not starts, it's that messagebox.show needs to be in a GUI.

Try Msgbox("Message") instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I started putting breakpoints in the main sub in case it was anything like that, but it wasn't hitting them. Shouldn't need a form to show a message box anyway I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

To help you in your transition from C# to VB.NET, this site [developer fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) will convert C# code to VB.NET. Hopefully you'll be able to see how the two languages correlate.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give that site a look.